# Magento 2 : How to Override Block File

Tags: magento2, blocks, override-block

I need override block file in custom module. Below is block file path.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php
```

How can I do that?

Yes, please check this error and code what i get.

[image]

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" type="Company\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" />
</config>
```

**Bloc/Adminhtml/order/Create/Search/Grid.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search;


class Grid extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Config $salesConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
        $this->_sessionQuote = $sessionQuote;
        $this->_salesConfig = $salesConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Prepare collection to be displayed in the grid
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $attributes = $this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes();
        /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $collection->setStore(
            $this->getStore()
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            $attributes
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
            'type_id',
            $this->_salesConfig->getAvailableProductTypes()
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'gift_message_available'
        );

       $collection->joinField(
                'qty_in_stock',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
        );

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare columns
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'index' => 'entity_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Product'),
                'renderer' => 'Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Product',
                'index' => 'name'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'column_css_class' => 'price',
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => $this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
                'rate' => $this->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()),
                'index' => 'price',
                'renderer' => 'Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Price'
            ]
        );
       $this->addColumn(
                'qty_in_stock',
                [
                'header' => __('Quantity In Stock'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'qty_in_stock'
                ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_products',
            [
                'header' => __('Select'),
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_products',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'sortable' => false
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'qty',
            [
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header' => __('Quantity'),
                'renderer' => 'Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Qty',
                'name' => 'qty',
                'inline_css' => 'qty',
                'type' => 'input',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 'qty'
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * Get grid url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'sales/*/loadBlock',
            ['block' => 'search_grid', '_current' => true, 'collapse' => null]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get selected products
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products', []);

        return $products;
    }

    /**
     * Add custom options to product collection
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _afterLoadCollection()
    {
        $this->getCollection()->addOptionsToResult();
        return parent::_afterLoadCollection();
    }


}
```

Just i need override this block and add new column for available qty for the product and it used when create order from admin. So please check let me know what i missing.

Comment: make sure you are passing all arguments, which are needed in the Parent constructor

Answer (score 2):

To overide block file you need to do this things.

1 – First of all create di.xml file in Folder Company/Extension/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" type="Company\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" />
</config>
```

2 – Now create Grid.php Block file in Folder Company\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search

```
<?php
    namespace Company\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search;

    class Grid extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid
    {
        // WRITE YOUR FUNCTION TO OVERIDE
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello Dhiren, Yes see that solution, but i can't get proper way can you please elaborate more. Thankyou Man

Comment: @Dhrumin can you tell me what error you face in above code?

Comment: @Dhrumin Preference is like rewrite in Magento 1.

Comment: Hello @Dhiren  please check again, i edit my question.

Comment: @Dhrumin if you have another question, then please ask new question. Becuase you have question that is not related to your previous question. This things help other in community. Hope you understand.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, i fixed this issue my self.

Comment: @Dhrumin if above answer will hel you, please accept it. It will help other in community as well.